# How do I check the status of Datastore indexes with a script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a script to vacuum/update indexes in Google Datastore using the *appcfg* script. However, I need a way to know when the indexes are finished being deleted/built.

How do I do this programmatically?

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) say "You can check the status of the Cloud Datastore instance's indexes from the Indexes page in the Cloud Platform Console." But that's in a GUI -- how do I do it from Python (or bash or Java)?

If I run *update_indexes* while indexes are being vacuumed, I get "Index being deleted cannot be (re)built until it is completely deleted." So, this is a way to determine index status in a script. Needless to say, it is too dangerous to try to overwrite indexes just to determine the status of indexes. But that indicates that in principle there is some way for scripts to do this.

Comment: You can try: use a dummy query and catch exception NeedIndexError()

Comment: That is only true if your query uses a certain index. It would take a lot of effort to figure out all necessary queries for that purpose. Note that my last paragraph does show that somehow the underlying API *does* know the status of every index as one iterates over all of them.

Comment: FWIW: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12251

Comment: It seems that things are moving to gcloud, though much functionality is still in preview. This capability seems to be missing, but this is where it will likely show up: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thank you. That suggests that the is no such API.